# Android: Change layout based on phone's default text size

Tags: android

Is there any way to change the layout of your app based on what text size the phone is set to? I know you can set your text so it will be static (stay the same size) but I've had some users complain because the app doesn't look good because of the large text. These are mainly older people who need the large text and it would be nice if there was an easy way to accomplish this without splitting one activity into two separate ones so they could still use it. Any ideas?